# TP4056 - high temperature

Tags: safety, charger, tp4056

The [TP4056 (1A)](https://acoptex.com/project/9446/basics-project-082a-lithum-battery-charger-tp4056-at-acoptexcom/) gets very hot (around 80-100*C) when charging the cell, so much so that it is impossible to hold it for more than a few seconds. Is it safe to use this circuit without any cooling?

[image: .]

Comment: You tell very little about your circuit, so based on what you tell, we can't answer if it is safe or not. How much in the temperature and what voltage you feed in to the charger? How is it connected anyway, just to know if it happens to be connected incorrectly.

Comment: So you have one of those cheap modules. It likely came with a manual how to use it and what are the expected temperatures. If it didn't, we can't say if it heats up as intended or if that is alarming.

Comment: I use these for a "long" time. Not yet remarked that it became "hot". Is the cell good? See also this https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056.html

Comment: cell is almost new, works fine

Comment: Temperature measured with IR thermometer?

Comment: don't have it, I used a simple electronic thermometer

Comment: http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf

Comment: As written in datasheet, this IC has thermal protection at 145°C, although this looks like emergency mode. I recommend to reduce charging current by increasing resistor value on pin 2. Side effect of this will be lengthening life of accumulator.